# Why is he so small?

Tags: aquarium

it’s kinda hard to see, but my flame tetras is super small! I do not know the gender of all of my fish, but 5 of my tetras are roughly the same size, but my 6’th one is really small. When I feed them, the big 5 are the only ones to get food really, but when the 6’th one has a chance, one of the big 5 nil his fin. Even when the small one gets food, he either spits it out or never eats it,(by biting it but not swallowing) I don’t want him to starve! Please help! (https://i.stack.imgur.com/R02Vm.jpg)